# I cant create new project in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I installed android studio and when I tried to open the android studio I cant run android emulator and It display the error report in below tab.
This is that error message

> `null value in entry:libOutputDir=null`

and line down display the `Build Failed`

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using the windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a gradle bug. Delete the gradle folder in the root directory of your application. Then open the app, let the studio rebuild the gradle again. This has been an issue for a lot of people.